# Button click getting delayed to show progress div

Tags: jquery

Every time i click the prepare result button the progress div is not displayed instantaneously rather it take time to show up.

http://beta.east-west.world/data

**--Javacript**

```
("#preview").click(function ()
{
    $('#divloading').show();

});

 <div id="divloading" style="display: none; text-align: center; width: 10000px" class="LoadingClass">
        <center>
            <div class="chart-container" id="chart"></div>

        </center>
    </div>
```

The div should have been displayed instantaneously but it's getting delayed.

```
Below is what is logged  for   $('#divloading').show();
    > 22:8:20:424 Test Click Time:End:
    > 22:8:20:423 Test Click Time:Start:
    > 22:8:9:506 Test Click Time:End:
    > 22:8:9:504 Test Click Time:Start:
```

Comment: Can you post the code

Comment: @VadimTatarnikov you can find the code on http://beta.east-west.world/Scripts/UserJs/data.js $("#preview").click(function ()

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code, but width:10000px - something strange, replace it with width:100%. maybe it helps.
Also recheck, maybe you have other on-click bindings, try to remove bootstrap classes btn, btn-success and try.
I haven't seen delay tho...

Comment: I have a added a time logger on the page to check the delay. For me it appears that there is pause b/w the click and the display of  the loading/ processing div.

Comment: @VadimTatarnikov i have set the width to 100%. There is no other on-click bindings for the same button.

Answer (score 0):

i have found ajax in your code ... which means your sending requests to the server ! and also means it's not totally an user-end operation and is using the internet ! so it's normal for it to take time to get the results from the server.

but what you have to worry about is the glitch it has which shows the loading page then disappears and appears again !

**EDIT :**

This is the code that is being fired on the click ... and this function is called at the end of it which has an ajax request in it : Report_Comparison();

```
$("#preview").click(function ()
{

$('#divloading').show().delay(0);

$('#ErrorWhileReportGeneration').html("");

var _GreaterOrSmaller = "<";
if ($("#rdo_sectorlargerthan").is(':checked') == true) {
    _GreaterOrSmaller = "" + ">";

}
if ($("#PartnersCountries").val() == null) {
    $('#divloading').hide();
    jAlert('Please select a partner country');

    return false;
}
if ($("#CompareCountryList").val() == null) {
    $('#divloading').hide();
    jAlert('Please select a country to compare');
    return false;
}
if ($("#IncludeComparisonInReport").is(':checked') == false) {
    $('#divloading').show();
    $("#report-table-container").show();
    _data = [];
    _Categoryies = [];
    _PointData = [];
    _AllData = [];
    if (SimpleReport() == false) {
        return false;
    }
}
else {
    $("#report-table-container").hide();
    $('#divloading').hide();
    jAlert("Include - Level 2 Selection work in development phase");
    return false;
}

$('#divloading').show();
Report_Comparison();
return false;
});
```

Comment: I need to show the processing/ loading section to make the user feel the process of getting the data has started and they don't click the button repeatedly

Comment: Yes I am using ajax but on the click the progress /loading page is getting delayed. Ajax is being called only after the loading/progress div is shown.

Comment: Buddy ! a request is being sent to the server every time i click the prepare button ! check out you browsers network requests to find out ! 3 requests are being sent every time i click the button

Comment: But I am using $('#divloading').show(); before any such request are sent out.

Comment: The first statement on the click event is $('#divloading').show()

Comment: Nope ! There's actually a function called when you click the prepare button it's named this : Report_Comparison and that function is firing an ajax request  ...

Comment: I have commented Report_Comparison now but still the delay.

Comment: There are a multitude of `.show()` calls within the onclick event listener. Any reason for this? Also, can you remove the `delay(0)` and try? P.S. I also concur that this is unrelated to the ajax request.

Comment: @cue I have removed the delay commented $('#divloading').show();
Report_Comparison();

Comment: i think you're not giving us the exact problem here ! because i receive the loading page right after i click the button and the only delay i get is on the loading page which is caused by the request ! i don't see any more delays !!

Comment: @RohitKumar let's make this a little easier. can you have nothing but `$('#divloading').show(); return false;` in your callback – so we're giving it a single job to do?

Comment: @Cue I have set it accordingly. What next I need to do so that there is code after $('#divloading').show()

Comment: @RohitKumar Can you now notice the considerable difference in the time it takes to show? I would now recommend adding code step-by-step, i.e. one logical statement at a time, to enable you to find out which part of your code is slowing things down.

Comment: @cue just a question, if I am calling the show function shouldn't it evoke immediately as my conditions are called latter.

Comment: @RohitKumar Yes, while this is a true statement, your function also continues to run multiple `show()` and `hide()` functions on the element depending on the conditionals. You want to eliminate the `show()` conditionals because you have already shown it on evoke.

Comment: @cue thanks for the clue, I will now try adding code step by step.